# How to apply label to instances of Managed Instance Group?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Is there a way to automatically apply [Labels](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources) to instances that are launched by a GCE Managed Instance Group (aka. [Instance Group Manager](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instanceGroupManagers))? I see that you can add [Network Tags](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/add-remove-network-tags) in the [Instance Template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instanceTemplates) (`properties.tags`), but I don’t see a way to add Labels for use in searching for labeled instances using [`instances/list`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/list#filter).

A workaround would be to manually call [`setLabels`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/setLabels) on instances from the Instance Template’s `startup-script`.

In AWS EC2, the equivalent would be to add [Tags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/API_Tag.html) to an [AutoScalingGroup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/API_AutoScalingGroup.html) with `PropagateAtLaunch: true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Labels](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources) are currently a beta feature. You can use the following command to create Compute Engine instance template with labels for your managed instance groups:

[gcloud beta compute instance-templates create NAME --labels=[KEY=VALUE,…]](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instance-templates/create)

Comment: Hi Kamran, I right understand, for now, boot disk labels must propagate from instance template labels?

Comment: Labels link is broken  for me despite the URL being correct.

Answer (score 1):

Automatically assigning Labels is available in the UI now: when editing an instance template, directly under the template's Name field you can expand "Manage Tags and Labels" and then add your labels in there.

*(I know this question is several years old, but I've posted this for anyone arriving here from search, like I did)*